# R - how to create a series of numbers where each is 10 times higher than previous one

Tags: r

I am taking my first steps in R. Have a series of exercises, but one is especially dificult for me. I need to create an series like this:

a1, b10, c100, d1000, ..., j1000000000

Combining following letters with numbers is not an issue, but how generate series of numbers, where each of them is previous one multiplied by 10?
I have gut feeling that it is not hard at all but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
10^(0:n)
```

For example

```
> 10^(0:3)
[1]    1   10  100 1000
```

Or even use a better way

```
x<-10^(0:3)
names(x)<-paste0("a_",0:3)
> x
 a_0  a_1  a_2  a_3 
   1   10  100 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

we can use `^`.
We may have to use `options(scipen=999)` to avoid incorporating scientific notation into the final character vector, if we have large numbers. some floating point issues may arise if the numbers get too high.

```
options(scipen=999)
paste0(letters, 10^(0:25))

 [1] "a1"                          "b10"                        
 [3] "c100"                        "d1000"                      
 [5] "e10000"                      "f100000"                    
 [7] "g1000000"                    "h10000000"                  
 [9] "i100000000"                  "j1000000000"                
[11] "k10000000000"                "l100000000000"              
[13] "m1000000000000"              "n10000000000000"            
[15] "o100000000000000"            "p1000000000000000"          
[17] "q10000000000000000"          "r100000000000000000"        
[19] "s1000000000000000000"        "t10000000000000000000"      
[21] "u100000000000000000000"      "v1000000000000000000000"    
[23] "w10000000000000000000000"    "x100000000000000008388608"  
[25] "y 999999999999999983222784"  "z10000000000000000905969664"
```

Comment: You'd have to use `(0:25)`